How to use custom models in this animation
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Canvas, useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFExporter } from 'three/examples/jsm/exporters/GLTFExporter';
import './App.css';

function Model() {
    const meshRef = useRef();
    const { scene } = useThree();
    const [mixer] = useState(() => new THREE.AnimationMixer());
    const clock = new THREE.Clock();
    const [exported, setExported] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (meshRef.current) {
            meshRef.current.name='myMesh'
            // Define keyframes
            const positionKF = new THREE.VectorKeyframeTrack(
                'myMesh.position',
                [0, 5], // times
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3] // values
            );

            const scaleKF = new THREE.VectorKeyframeTrack(
                'myMesh.scale',
                [0, 5], // times
                [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5] // values
            );

            const rotationKF = new THREE.QuaternionKeyframeTrack(
                'myMesh.quaternion',
                [0, 5], // times
                [
                    0, 0, 0, 1,
                    ...new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 4)).toArray()
                ] // values
            );

            // Create animation clip
            const clip = new THREE.AnimationClip('Action', -1, [positionKF, scaleKF, rotationKF]);

            // Add the clip to the mixer
            const action = mixer.clipAction(clip, meshRef.current);
            action.play();

            // Export the model after the animation is complete
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (!exported) {
                    handleExport(scene, clip);
                    setExported(true);
                }
            }, 5000); // 5 seconds for the animation to complete
        }
    }, [mixer, exported, scene]);

    useFrame(() => {
        const delta = clock.getDelta();
        mixer.update(delta);
    });

    const handleExport = (scene, clip) => {
        const gltfExporter = new GLTFExporter();
        const options = {
            binary: true,
            animations: [clip],
        };
        gltfExporter.parse(scene, function (result) {
            if (result instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
                saveArrayBuffer(result, 'scene.glb');
            } else {
                const output = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
                console.log(output);
                saveString(output, 'scene.gltf');
            }
        }, function (error){
            console.log("Some error")
            console.log(error);
        }, options);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        function save(blob, filename) {
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = filename;
            link.click();
        }
        function saveString(text, filename) {
            save(new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' }), filename);
        }
        function saveArrayBuffer(buffer, filename) {
            save(new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), filename);
        }
    };

    return (
            <mesh ref={meshRef}>
                <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
            </mesh>
    );
}

// App component to set up the scene and export functionality
export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Canvas camera={{ position: [-8, 5, 8] }}>
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
                <Model />
                <OrbitControls />
            </Canvas>
        </>
    );
}

I am able to export a the cube, with its animation. However, according to another forum (Exporting an animated scene with GLTFExporter in ThreeJS?)
We are not able to export animations with materials. How do I import a model now, with animations preloaded, inside such a scene?
Can anyone help me out please?
Thanks

That is unclear for me a bit… Are you talking about material or animation? Make sure that you tick, proper export options in your software (materials, etc).

I meant to say, how do I provide custom models over here, with animations already attached to them? and if I add some key framing animations over here, will they export those animated models, with my keyframes animations along with their original textures?
